# Subtract one row of two results

Tags: mysql

I have one table with three columns like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status="ok"
# Result 1
/*--------------------------------------------
    qnt     name        status
    10      prod1       ok
    10      prod2       ok
--------------------------------------------*/


SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status="deleted"
# Result 2
/*--------------------------------------------
    qnt     name        status
    2       prod1       deleted
    3       prod2       deleted
--------------------------------------------*/
```

I want result like this (is it possible ?):

```
# Result3 = (Result 1) - (Result 2)
/*--------------------------------------------
    qnt     name
    8       prod1
    7       prod2
--------------------------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   ok.qnt - deleted.qnt AS qnt,
   ok.name
FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status="ok") ok
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status="deleted") deleted
   ON ok.name = deleted.name
```